# UWP Touch Volume Control

Tags: c#, android, uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I need to implement Tap (Touch) volume control using UWP code.

For example, if I tap a button in my terminal, the volume of tapping sound could control in App settings. This control must link into the mobile or any other devices.

Few investigations: Tap sound from an adjustment of Ringtone Volume in our mobile. so we need to get the response from Ringtone settings.

I've searched most about this, but couldn't find the solution.

**Update**

at Slider change event:

```
Slider slider = sender as Slider; 
double volumeLevel = slider.Value / 10; 
ElementSoundPlayer.Volume = volumeLevel; 
//CurrVolumeLevel = (double)ElementSoundPlayer.Volume; 
CurrVolumeLevel = volumeLevel;
```

At pageload:

```
//player = new MediaPlayer(); 
CurrVolumeLevel = (double)ElementSoundMode.Default; 
ElementSoundPlayer.State = ElementSoundPlayerState.Aut
```

o

Comment: I've silly doubt. in our usual smartphone, we have touch sounds and i can hear 1 sound for all the apps it seems. so tap sound is control by system or app owners. Like tap sound is defined or vary from app?

Comment: at Slider change event: Slider slider = sender as Slider;
            double volumeLevel = slider.Value / 10;

            ElementSoundPlayer.Volume = volumeLevel;
            //CurrVolumeLevel = (double)ElementSoundPlayer.Volume;
            CurrVolumeLevel = volumeLevel;
           At pageload:  this.InitializeComponent();
            //player = new MediaPlayer();
            CurrVolumeLevel = (double)ElementSoundMode.Default;
            ElementSoundPlayer.State = ElementSoundPlayerState.Auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement Tap (Touch) volume and control it's volume, you could refer [Sound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/sound) official documentation.

> UWP provides an easily accessible sound system that allows you to simply "flip a switch" and get an immersive audio experience across your entire app.

The ElementSoundPlayer is an integrated sound system within XAML, and when turned on all default controls will play sounds automatically.

```
ElementSoundPlayer.State = ElementSoundPlayerState.On;
```

> All sounds within the app can be dimmed with the Volume control. However, sounds within the app cannot get louder than the system volume.

To set the app volume level, call:

```
ElementSoundPlayer.Volume = 0.5;
```

Where maximum volume (relative to system volume) is 1.0, and minimum is 0.0 (essentially silent).

**Update**

Please try the following simple code.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ElementSoundPlayer.State = ElementSoundPlayerState.On;
    CurrentVol.Value = ElementSoundPlayer.Volume * 10;
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Slider slider = sender as Slider;
    double volumeLevel = slider.Value / 10;
    ElementSoundPlayer.Volume = volumeLevel;
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Name="CurrentVol" Maximum="10" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
    <Button Content="ClickMe"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: May i confirm this Sound control for managing the Ringtone volume in windows mobile?. coz nrml media volume control can't control the touch(tap) volume. Touch volume is adjust by ringtone volume.

Comment: Yep, its relative to system volume not media volume.

Comment: But it could be managed separately with `ElementSoundPlayer.Volume` property.

Comment: Zhu, tried above solution, but failed. it doesn't make changes in app or in system volume. and even i assigned the volume and play with elementplayer also has no changes. so this not helpful.

Comment: Very strange, I could use `ElementSoundPlayer.Volume` to mange elementplayer and it works in my side. Could you share your full code sample?

Comment: @Mohanas, you'd better put the code in your case update.

Comment: Nico, did ur code supports to change the volume in touch terminal?

Comment: And the different is the  `ElementSoundPlayer.State = ElementSoundPlayerState.On` in my side.

Comment: yes after set it 'on', its wrked. but button not having its own touch sound? or we need to play the touch sound individually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181463/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-mohana-s).

Comment: UWP button has `ElementSound` and you could also set it in xaml  `<Button Content="ClickMe" ElementSoundMode="Default"/>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its wrked for me