# How to changle application volume

Tags: uwp

How can I change the application volume in UWP. I tried with global api provided by Microsoft but the value of the volume mixer in the application doesn't changed. Did I miss anything?[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554504/uwp-touch-volume-control) this will decrease the volume but not the volume mixer. How can I control volume mixer.

Comment: Yes, I check the reply but is doesn't help me. Because the volume mixer of the application didn't change with the Sound global api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> enter link description here this will decrease the volume but not the volume mixer

[**Sound Global API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/sound?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sound-global-api) is used to easily accessible sound system that allows you to simply "flip a switch" and get an immersive audio experience across your entire app. It can manage `ElementSoundPlayer` that is an integrated sound system within XAML. But it can't change app's volume in the volume mixer. Currently, UWP does not provide such api manage volume mixer.

The legacy [win32 app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322736/7254781) could control volume mixer. If you do want to control volume mixer within UWP, you could use desktop bridge convert win32 app to uwp. This related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root).